# Can a homeowners insurance demand that I perform specific maintenance at my home?

Tags: united-states, insurance, home-insurance, michigan

Our insurance company sent someone out to take photos of our home.  They then sent us a letter stating we must fix cracked windows and remove any foliage that is near or hangs over house and out-building.  Nothing specific or we would be cancelled.  All foliage is living, nothing dead.  Can they do this? We live in Michigan.

Comment: What @littleadv describes in his answer is Risk Mitigation.  Insurers are really big on risk mitigation in the business insurance world, and now it's apparently filtering down into the residential arena.

Comment: You're lucky that you got a letter.  When we moved into our house, the insurance rep did a walk by and they decided to cancel our homeowners insurance due to a lack of railing on a deck, with no demand to fix, just a cancel of our policy.  The silly thing was that the deck was in compliance with local regulations (it was a low deck less than 30" off the ground at its highest point, which was the local regulation for needing a railing).  However, the silver lining was that when we got insurance from another company (with no railing stipulation), the rates were less for better coverage.

Comment: I think the question really is, "is there anything in Michigan or federal law that entitles me to keep my existing insurance on a generally well-maintained home with cracked windows and nearby foliage?". I think it's fairly clear they *can't* legally "force" you to do specific maintenance on your home. But what they might be able to do is (a) cancel your policy; (b) keep taking the premiums but then refuse to pay out on the policy if you ever claim, on grounds that you're in breach. What you're hoping is you can force them to continue insuring you.

Comment: With the increase in forest fires, many companies have started insisting on proper defensible space around the house, with specifications given. Otherwise they won't insure. On the upside, my insurance company will proactively send people out to spray coat my house in a fire situation (also a loss-prevention measure for them). Where my parents live, the local fire department will take you for a personal tour of your neighborhood pointing out which houses they won't bother trying to save in a forest fire, and which ones have done the right thing.

Comment: I in fact once had an insurance company do this to me directly after I switched to them (not naming names, but their initials were Allstate). Arguably a bait-and-switch. Cost me about $500, and that's with me doing some of the work myself.

Answer (score 19):

> Can they do this?

Yes.

They're trying to identify potential hazards/liability and have you mitigate that before problems happen for which they'd have to pay. Cracked windows and seemingly neglected yard seem to suggest that you're not maintaining the property (that's how the insurance company sees it, even if it disagrees with the actual reality).

Insurance companies are having a lot of losses due to the various weather events (wildfires, wind damage, floods), and in many States regulators resist their push to allow them to raise premiums to cover those losses. Harassing homeowners in this way is a way to put pressure on the politicians to allow them to charge more.

In California, for example, not only do they have these proactive inspections and cancellations, but some insurers leave the State altogether since the increasing risk of wildfires and the regulatory resistance to allow increasing premiums makes it much less profitable for them to operate in the State.

Comment: It's likely that this is written directly into your insurance policy. You might want to sit down and read through it again, making notes about limitations and obligations.

Comment: Actually, the window “just” cracked.  It is one on 2 that we did not completely replace less then a year ago.  We are replacing the 2 in a month or so.  I understand them wanting windows fixed, so do we.  Thats why we are replacing them.  The foliage is trimmed and not neglected. I don’t want to chop down the trees and bushes that are in excellent shape.  We take very good care of our home and yard.  Eg: we paid a large sum of money to have a dying tree removed last summer and another trimmed that was becoming a nuisance.  You should not assume we are neglectful .  We are not.

Comment: It is happening in Florida as well, but mainly forcing homeowners to get a new roof.

Comment: @Michael try not to take the comment personally (re: seemingly neglectful). The fact is that if all you have to go by is a picture of some cracked windows and trees that don't look like they have been trimmed, you get the neglectful rubber stamp. Remember, the insurance company is not a person but a collection of rules and policies designed to make a profit. They don't care if you care for your home well or not, they only care about what they have to pay out for (or what they can charge more for).

Comment: And if it's maintenance you are doing anyway, all you have to do is say "yes, this just happened, we're aware of it and fixing it, no need to send threatening letters." It gets fixed, they have no complaints, whole thing goes away.

Comment: @keshlam I have a very different experience. At least in California I've seen cases where they'd say "we don't care what you do *now*, it wasn't done when we looked so FU, you're cancelled". The insurance companies are being brutal right now.

Comment: @littleadv: That doesn't seem to be what was described in this case. And if so there isn't a lot we can say beyond "shop for new insurance after addressing these issues."

Comment: "seemingly neglected yard", based on a short description of a mail sent by an insurance company, you're a bit quick to jump to conclusions

Comment: @njzk2 that's the point of view of the insurance company, I'm sorry if my point didn't come across.

Comment: @Michael I'm not the one making assumptions, the insurance company does. And it does it based on a superficial inspection made by an overworked contractor paid by volume. They don't have neither time nor will to dig deep/investigate/hear your side. They're just collecting information that would help them lose as little as possible on you as their customer.

Comment: An arbitrary *yes* w/o reading the contract? More like *almost undoubtedly*, yes, *they have their ducks in a row*. However it still depends on what the contract [*legally*](https://money.stackexchange.com/a/158499/67482) states.

Comment: @Mazura please provide an example of a law or insurance policy that would prohibit insurer to condition coverage on homeowners' mitigating risks through adequate maintenance.

Answer (score 12):

> Can they do this?

If your insurance contract says they are allowed to cancel the insurance if you don't make certain maintenance work they identified as possible hazards, then they can do this.

If your insurance contract says that they have to insure you no matter what you do with your house, they can't.

So you will have to dig out the copy of your insurance policy and read it.

Comment: "If your *state law* says that they have to insure you no matter what..." FTFY.

Comment: let's not forget that not all clauses in all contracts are necessarily legal, and in some jurisdictions may just become void.

Comment: If op have cracked windows, shouldn't insurance pay for that? cc @michael

Comment: @akostadinov The insurance I'm aware of pays on _claims_, and then what you have to pay regularly to keep the insurance can change based on whether you have made claims (and their nature).

Comment: @akostadinov Last time I renegotiated my home insurance policy, windows and other glass items were an optional package. Which I, for example, don't need because I own an apartment and all the windows are communal property of the HOA.